# Advertised Bandwidth 0 B/s: Why?

Tags: bandwidth

My 7 year old relay was down for a week.

In `torrc` I have:

```
RelayBandwidthRate 180 MBytes
RelayBandwidthBurst 200 MBytes
```

But even so I get:

```
Advertised Bandwidth 0 B/s
```

in https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#details/63C6AB74A5C288C2159DDC783BB00F88AB44427C

I understand that Advertised Bandwidth is computed from what others measure, but if the Advertised Bandwidth is 0 why would anyone test if that is true?

(I perfectly understand why it is being kicked out as Guard node for the next 14 days).

Comment: When did your relay come back online? Your advertised bandwidth is 0 since your relay reports having sent/received 0 bytes. Your consensus weight is 28000, so your relay should start seeing traffic and your advertised bandwidth should go up the next time it uploads its server descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seeing as your advertised bandwidth is now `16.44 MiB/s`, this confirms what I had in mind. All you needed to do is wait a bit, I had this problem too. This might be because someone tested your bandwidth while you were down, I think it can take up to 48 hours to recheck your bandwidth again.